# Android Gradle Plugin: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is my first time using Android Studio, and I'm trying to run my first Hello World app,
But when I open Android Studio, and it's trying to build the Gradle, the following error is displayed in Build View:

> Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.3', apply: false]
> was not found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.3', apply: false] was
>   not found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.1.3')
>   Searched in the following repositories:
>   Gradle Central Plugin Repository
>   Google
>   MavenRepo

**build.gradle**:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**settings.gradle**:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Hello World"
include ':app'
```

I tried the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71784769/13715670) (change the version to 7.1.2),
And also tried to download and [set Gradle manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssyvz.jpg),
But to no avail.

Please enlighten my eyes and tell me what can I do to solve the problem that is happening to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, Adding Android Studio to the Windows Firewall list fixed the same problem for me. It wasn't added by default, or maybe I clicked something wrong during installation.

- Start > Windows Firewall
- In the left panel "Allow an app for feature through Windows Firewall"
- Change settings
- If Android Studio is not in the list: "Allow another app" and find the exe from the desktop/start menu shortcut
- I restarted windows; maybe restarting Android Studio is enough

There are probably many causes/solutions for this error, but this worked for me.

Comment: Indeed, it turns out that this was a network problem.
This is not exactly a problem with the firewall settings,
But my internet is blocked by the network provider.
An open internet connection has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open `build.gradle` (Module: 'name of your project.app')

At the top, confirm you have the below `id` in the `plugins{...}`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is in the `build.gradle` file in the `app` folder, And yet it makes that error.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to `Gradle`

open

> C:/user/YouPcUserName/

and Delete the `./gradle` and `AndroidStudio` folder completely

**Now run Android Studio and it well work**