# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.2'] was not found in any of the following. Android Studio Error

Tags: android, runtime-error

[image: Error in Gradle]

i reinstalled Android studio twice and got the same error.
my Pc is an

Ryzen5 3600
16Gb Ram

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71780967/android-gradle-plugin-7-1-3-plugin-id-com-android-application-version-7

Comment: Don't work :/ for me