# Flutter error resolving plugin - failed to start

Tags: flutter

I am on windows 11 and installed everything yesterday so I think it is updated. I am new to this and don't understand these terms. I just started the course and been stuck with this error whole day. Please help. I have seen a few post like this on gradle forum as well without any solution.

```
What went wrong: Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false]

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.

> Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\bhanu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.101\descriptors\com.android.application\com.android.application.gradle.plugin\7.3.0\11cd36a7dcab7d14d0c14c5e6c7582e3\descriptor.bin

* Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

I updated the android studio and other dependencies, opened it let the gradle build which is frustrating since this is a dual core PC.

flutter doctor
[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94l2W.png)

Comment: Please attach flutter doctor -v command;s output

Comment: i have added it please look into it

Comment: this will help you. require minor changes:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71784769/4373661

Comment: build.gradle file has this inside plugins segment, nothing similar to answer you  suggested -----      plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}