# Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.9.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: android

I just installing android studio with the latest update, but gradle sync failed.

`
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.9.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.9.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin:1.9.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Google
  MavenRepo
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:237)
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$resolvePluginRequests$3(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:167)

**attached screencapture for reference here :
[build.gradle + setting.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4wAH.png)**

Comment: Please share the content of your build.gradle files

Comment: Hi @Cristi
Thank you for your response. Here the build.gradle project file

`projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias("com.android.application:8.3.0") apply false
    alias("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:1.9.0") apply false 
}`

Comment: Just give the complete files in the question. I cannot tell with just two lines.

Comment: attached screencapture for your reference [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4wAH.png) . looking forward to hear from you @Cristi

Comment: See here a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71780967/android-gradle-plugin-7-1-3-plugin-id-com-android-application-version-7

Comment: all the answer not match for myissue @Cristi